# Rails error: uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, restful-authentication

Working my way through clarkware's [iphone-rails-tutorial](http://github.com/clarkware/iphone-rails-tutorial) and trying to build and run the final rails code that is included but I get this error in the server's console whenever I try to access localhost:3000/

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Authentication):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `<class:ApplicationController>'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/goals_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'

Rendered /Users/joeuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.6ms)
```

Previous included "milestones" of sample code have run just fine. Only the final one throws error...

What does this mean? My uninitiated guess is that there's an authentication gem of some sort missing but I can't figure out which one. there's nothing listed in the Gemfile other than the default rails & sqlite3-ruby...and there's no mention of any authentication frameworks in the documentation.

anyone understand this error or familiar enough with the tutorial to know what's going on?

*I can't seem to find a forum related to this tutorial so I thought I'd inquire here. Please direct me to active forum if you know of one.*

Answer (score 10):

I've seen this happen when I created an app with one of the rails betas, in my case beta3, and then updated it to the release version. In order to get it working you could try adding:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

to your config/application.rb.

YMMV

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I was able to get the tutorial to run and found in the latest download of the tutorial that this line is there in the config/application.rb.  I needed the help that brought me to this post because I am writing the tutorial app from scratch and my config/application.rb did not have that line.